# Hw to track email with sendgrid api?

Tags: email, sendgrid

I'm trying to track an email using sendGrid Webhook event notifier API.

I configured the apps: clicktrack, opentrack & eventnotify to true,

I created a POSTURL using RequestPin,

I activated the event notification from mail settings in my dashboard &  I checked all the events, when I press the testYourIntegration button, I get the example post request to the created url.

I used this code as described in the official documentation:

```
string apikey = "......."
sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get( apikey ))
to_email = Email("....@gmail.com")   
from_email =Email ("....")
subject= '...'
content=Content('..')
mail =Mail(...)
....
```

to send the mails & it works fine, & I get the email.
Now when I open the email sent by code, I don't get the notification in the URL,

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a config issue, I retried the steps above & they worked fine, not sure what went wrong the first time